# почему если из скрипта заморозить позицию, то разморозятся повороты RigedBody

Tags: unity3d

> Проблема в том что мне нужно заморозить только позицию Y, но при этом почему то размораживаются повороты.
> Если добавить строчку с повторной заморозкой поворотов, то не будет замораживаться позиция Y.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Ladder"))
        {
            onGraund = false;
            isHit = true;
            
            _playerRigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionY;
            
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Ladder"))
        {
            isHit = false;
            _playerRigidbody.useGravity = true;
            _playerRigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
            _playerRigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Читай: [Rigidbody.constraints](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-constraints.html), там все есть.